# Using SQL, how can I improve counting frequencies of only pairs that appear reciprocally in both columns

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, group-by, count

**Can my solution be improved?**

I have a couple of tables:

**senders:** (Note: `email_id` is a primary key)

```
| email_id | sender_id |
|----------|-----------|
| 1        | 80        |
| 2        | 80        |
| 3        | 80        |
| 4        | 80        |
| 5        | 87        |
```

**receivers**

```
| email_id | receiver_id |
|----------|-------------|
| 1        | 87          |
| 2        | 185         |
| 3        | 185         |
| 3        | 232         |
| 4        | 87          |
| 5        | 80          |
```

Desired Output

```
| A  | B  | Frequency |
|----|----|-----------|
| 80 | 87 | 3         |
```

Here is my current solution:

```
with g as (
    select
        s.sender_id as Sender,
        r.receiver_id as Receiver,
        count(*) as Frequency
    from receivers r, senders s
    where s.email_id = r.email_id
    group by Sender, Receiver
)
select
    g1.Sender as A,
    g1.Receiver as B,
    g1.Frequency + g2.Frequency as Frequency
from g g1, g g2
where g1.Sender = g2.Receiver 
    and g1.Receiver = g2.Sender
    and A < B
order by Frequency desc
;
```

With respect to databases: I am seeking an ANSI compliant solution that will work across different databases.

Comment: What is the problem with your current solution?

Comment: Also, please tag your question with the database that you are using: mysq, oracle, sql-server...?

Comment: @GMB It works, but I feel like it might be doing too much there. Perhaps there is a more elegant way of doing what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you want `least()` and `greatest()` - if your database supports them:

```
select
    least(s.sender_id, r.receiver_id) a, 
    greatest(s.sender_id, r.receiver_id) b,
    count(*) frequency
from senders s
inner join receivers r on r.email_id = s.email_id
group by least(s.sender_id, r.receiver_id), greatest(s.sender_id, r.receiver_id)
order by frequency desc
```

---

In SQLite, the equivalent functions are `min()` and `max()`:

```
select
    min(s.sender_id, r.receiver_id) a, 
    max(s.sender_id, r.receiver_id) b,
    count(*) frequency
from senders s
inner join receivers r on r.email_id = s.email_id
group by min(s.sender_id, r.receiver_id), max(s.sender_id, r.receiver_id)
order by frequency desc
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=aeea39dc062f6984a2798840349c24a0)**:

```
 a |   b | frequency
-: | --: | --------:
80 |  87 |         3
80 | 185 |         2
80 | 232 |         1
```

---

If you want to filter only on tuples that have roundtrip communications, you can add a `having` clause to the query:

```
select
    min(s.sender_id, r.receiver_id) a, 
    max(s.sender_id, r.receiver_id) b,
    count(*) frequency
from senders s
inner join receivers r on r.email_id = s.email_id
group by min(s.sender_id, r.receiver_id), max(s.sender_id, r.receiver_id)
having min(s.sender_id) <> max(s.sender_id)
order by frequency desc
```

Comment: Let me try this :) I'm hopeful. I'll be back.

Comment: @RaminMelikov: in SQLite, you need `MIN()` and `MAX()` instead of `LEAST()` and `GREATEST()`. See my updated answer (and the demo).

Comment: But this one includes the counts of those that are not in my desired output. I only want to count those that have roundtrip communications.

Comment: @RaminMelikov: ok. See the 3rd query in my answer.

Comment: Cool! I see it works on Fiddle. I'll try implementing it now.

Comment: @OMB, I now understand everything there but the `having min(s.sender_id) <> max(s.sender_id)` part. Would you mind helping me understand what that does exactly?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to count the emails regardless of the direction.  In your example data, each email has only one receiver.  If that is the case, you can do:

```
select min(s.sender_id, r.receiver_id) as a, 
       max(s.sender_id, r.receiver_id) as b,
       count(*) as frequency
from senders s inner join
     receivers r
     on r.email_id = s.email_id
group by min(s.sender_id, r.receiver_id), max(s.sender_id, r.receiver_id) 
order by frequency desc;
```

SQLite uses `min()` and `max()` with multiple arguments for what other databases use `least()` and `greatest()` for.

Comment: Thank you, Gordon. This was almost there and similar to OMB's solution. His was correct, though, as it matched my desired output. Thank you anyway!

Comment: @RaminMelikov . . . I see the answer was edited so it works in SQLite.  Now it is fine.